# Container restart policy does not work with Docker Compose (works with Docker CLI)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7-alpine
    ports:
      - 8881:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
    restart: always
```

And start with `docker-compose up -d`. If I restart Docker engine, the container created by this will not auto restart.

Now say I start the container with this:

```
docker run -d -p 8882:80 \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml \
    --restart always \
    traefik:1.7-alpine
```

This one will start automatically if I restart the Docker engine.

What am I doing wrong with the Docker Compose version?

**EDIT:**

I created another test using a different image (just to be sure it was not something related to Traefik) and I believe I pinpointed the problem to the volumes:

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  traefik:
    image: containous/whoami
    volumes:
      - ./placeholder.txt:/placeholder.txt
    restart: always
```

Docker CLI:

```
docker run -d \
    -v ./placeholder.txt:/placeholder.txt \
    --restart always \
    containous/whoami
```

And here's a diff (`inspect`) between them (left: compose; right: cli) : https://www.diffchecker.com/CC0WV3va

[image]
[image]
[image]

Removing the volume line from the Docker Compose version "solves the issue".

Comment: If you run `docker inspect` on the container created with docker-compose, what does it say the restart policy is? There should be a field named "RestartPolicy". (I'm trying to figure out whether it's a problem with docker-compose not setting the correct restart policy, or with docker itself ignoring it)

Comment: Could you provide `docker` and `docker-compose` versions, along with your host OS? Do you have the same issue when not mounting `/var/run/docker.sock`? How do you restart Docker engine?

Comment: @lgpasquale Yes, `RestartPolicy` is available in both and they have the same value.

Comment: @norbjd I use Docker for Windows but I'm doing all this within WSL with Docker installed but `DOCKER_HOST` pointing to Docker for Windows (more info: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly). `Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90` and `docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01` Also, I'm restarting Docker by clicking the tray icon in Windows and selecting "Restart...".

Comment: Can you reproduce the error with a volume instead of a bind mount : `-v test-volume:/path/to/placeholder/`?

Comment: @norbjd Is that on Docker CLI or Compose? Tried with `docker run -d -v test-volume:/placeholder.txt --restart always containous/whoami` but the container restarts just fine.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant with `docker-compose` like `volumes: - test-volume:/path/to/placeholder/`.

Comment: @norbjd That requires me to create a volume beforehand? `ERROR: Named volume "test-volume:/placeholder.txt:rw" is used in service "traefik" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`

Comment: Yes you could create it by defining a `volumes` section in your `docker-compose.yml` : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference. The volume should then be mapped to a directory in the container : `test-volume:/path/to/a/folder`.

Comment: I think it might be related to this (https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1560) so I'm closing this question for now.